# Is there a way to recover the BIOS of a Razer Blade laptop?

Tags: laptop, bios, restore

I have a Razer Blade 15" (2019) Advanced laptop and I've been having problems with the USB ports. I've tried downgrading its version but the installers for Razer's old BIOS versions won't let me install them since I already have the latest version.

Resetting the BIOS settings won't work either.

I have a feeling that my BIOS is corrupt, so is there any way of restoring it?

Its also been over a year since Razer released the latest BIOS for my laptop model. Not sure if they would even release another one.